# Search with a single TextBox that will filter every column in a table?

Tags: excel, vba, search, excel-2013

```vb
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

texto = "*" & Sheets("bdd").TextBox1.Text & "*"
Range("E5").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=texto
Range("F5").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=texto
Range("K5").AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=texto

If Sheets("bdd").TextBox1.Text = "" Then Range("E5").AutoFilter Field:=5
If Sheets("bdd").TextBox1.Text = "" Then Range("F5").AutoFilter Field:=6
If Sheets("bdd").TextBox1.Text = "" Then Range("K5").AutoFilter Field:=11

End Sub
```

When I write something in my TextBox, it will filter in a way where every column needs to have same values to show me something.

Is it possible to search with just one TextBox in all columns of my table?

A "general searcher" of a table, so if you have three columns (fruit, units, country) and you write "Me" it will show not just Melon (for fruit) but also Mexico (for country) or any entry that has that string.

Comment: The problem with that approach is if (for example) there's no "fruit" match then that will hide all of the rows, so even if there's a "country" match you won't see it...  You could add a column which joins all of the fields you want to search, and then filter on that.

Comment: You can use advanced filter

Comment: In such cases it is easy to do what you describe using an auxiliary column. You don't need a TextBox. You write in cell A1 (or whatever you want) what you want to be contained in the cells of columns E, F, K. This auxiliary column will have a vba formula that will check if the value of A1 is contained in the cells and will return TRUE or FALSE. You will only filter the auxiliary column. See an answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76230032/15794828

Comment: Thank you to all, it help a lot and yeah it work better than most of another approaches